# SurfFeaturesFinder

Tags: opencv

I tried to use "SurfFeatureDetector" and "SurfDescriptorExtractor" but in new version 2.4.1 we just have "SurfFeaturesFinder" with an operator that needs a struct "ImageFeatures" i developed an example to use it in feature description as bellow:

```
//Detect the keypoints and Calculate descriptors using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;
detail::SurfFeaturesFinder detector(minHessian);
detail::ImageFeatures myobjfeatures,myscnfeatures;

detector (img_object,myobjfeatures);// i have an error here
detector (img_scene,myscnfeatures);
```

i have this error:Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001cbe30..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes are there. You need to include `<opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>` and link against `opencv_nonfree241.lib`.